# Non-obligational sense/use of "should" for discussing future plans

Tags: modal-verbs, should

In discussion of translating between English and another language I saw some people insisting English "should" must be translated as though it has the obligation sense even in contexts like these:

- I don't know what I **should** do next weekend.
- What **should** we have for dinner tonight?

But to me, a native English speaker, the *should* in these examples does not carry any different meaning than if we'd used *will* or *shall* or *am/are going to*.

Looking in some dictionaries though, I'm having trouble seeing which sense of *should* it would be.

Is this a correct usage, how should we define it, where is it covered in English dictionaries?

Comment: I would only use _should_ in those context if there was some degree of obligation (you have promised your child an outing at the weekend but now feel you really  ought to visit a relative).

Comment: @KateBunting: It seems to be covered by Oxford here at 1.2: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/should and by Collins here at 5: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/should ... still working on it though ...